# How do I check if record exists in table from a 1 Billion rows table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Data Scraping script.

It runs and scrapes records, saves into a 10-columns table.

For the records already existing in DB, I need to update the old records if it is not updated for the past 2 days.

My table has fields `scraper_run_inserted` (DATETIME value when record is inserted) and `scraper_run_updated` (DATETIME value when record is updated)

That table has 1 billion rows,

When script starts, I get all records which are not needed to update.

**THIS QUERY TAKES SO LONG...**

```
$doNotupdateLicencesList = "SELECT DISTINCT(licence_id) FROM `{$onegov_main_table}` WHERE scraper_run_updated >= '{$prev_date_to_check}'";
$doNotupdateLicencesList = $conn->prepare($doNotupdateLicencesList);
$doNotupdateLicencesList->execute();
$doNotupdateLicencesList = $doNotupdateLicencesList->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

in `$doNotupdateLicencesList` array I have all records which I do not want to update.

My scraper iterates over pages of the website and grabs a list `licence_ids` from every page.

this array `$allLicencesOnThisPage` holds all licences on a particular page.

This is what I do...

**THIS LOOP TAKES LONG TOO**

```
foreach ($doNotupdateLicencesList as $licence_id) {
    if (isset($allLicencesOnThisPage[$licence_id])) {
        unset($allLicencesOnThisPage[$licence_id]);
    }
}
```

What do I need to do optimize the code?

During scraping, should I make a `SELECT` query to database for each entry to check if exists and not have updated for past 2 days?

Comment: Could you run same query on SQL Server Management Studio and attach execution plan here? It would give information where your SQL is bottlenecking.

Comment: I do not have SQL Server Management Studio. I have only MySQL installed.

Comment: Alright, you have tagged SQL Server at the beginning, that's why I asked.

Comment: sorry, I removed that tag

Comment: What is `licence_id` type? Do you have any indexes setup? Seeing the table schema would help dramatically.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: licence_id is varchar... I have added index as `aynber` suggested in answer below

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to take 2 steps to speed things up:

First, alter the query to get the licenses not inserted or updated in the past 2 days:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(licence_id) FROM `{$onegov_main_table}` 
   WHERE scraper_run_inserted < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
   AND scraper_run_updated < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Second, you want to create an index on all of the tables you'll be querying to speed up the queries. This will only need to be done once.

```
ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD INDEX license_insert (`licence_id`, `scraper_run_inserted`, `scraper_run_updated`);
```

These two steps will reduce the query time and the number of licenses you need to check. If there aren't a ton of licenses, then you can also add it into the query and remove the PHP loop.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(licence_id) FROM `{$onegov_main_table}` 
   WHERE scraper_run_inserted < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
   AND scraper_run_updated < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
   AND licence_id NOT IN (*comma separated list of IDs here*)
```

Comment: *comma separated list of IDs here* ... good suggestion... There are maximum 500 licences on each page.... so its good

Comment: but wait.... running a SELECT query on `onegov_main_table` again and again would take more time :(

Comment: If you mean for the NOT IN, you only need to run it once per list of IDs. Test the query out with and without the IDs to see which is more cost effective.

Comment: yes, the query you posted takes equal amount of time as it takes for the one I posted in question.... so running this query for each set of IDs is not good